# Line break after substring

Tags: java, regex, substring

If I use a pattern and matcher in Java how can I add a line break right after I find the substring?
**UPDATE**

I found a solution using the `replaceAll(String,String);` method

**Thanks a lot guys my solution has been formatted below**

```
 String contentsToSearch = "This is an example string /* example comment in my string */ with some extra text following my inline comment";
//String regex = "[*/]" ;
//Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
//Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(contentsToSearch);

//if(matcher.find()){
      // add a line break to the string i am searching
 //}else{
      // print out my string regularly
  //    System.out.println(contentsToSearch);
 //}
 contentsToSearch = contentsToSearch.replaceAll("\\*/", "\\*/\n");
 System.out.println(contentsToSearch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do:

```
contentsToSearch = contentsToSearch.replaceAll("(/\\*|\\*/)", "$1\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("yourRegex","$0\n")
```

`$0` represents group 0 which is part matched by entire regex. Also instead of `\n` you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to pick separator used in your OS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice tutorial on Matcher at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html

Looks like  replaceFirst(String) and replaceAll(String) described on that page could work. They will replace the matching text and you can replace with same text plus the \n.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this instead of using matcher.find:

```
System.out.println(contentsToSearch.replaceAll("\\*/", "\n"));
```